# Run inno script compiler in gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, innodb

I enable CI/CD in gitlab.
I would like to, in the build job, compile a setup made with inno setup. This is yaml gitlab configuration related to build job:

```yaml
    build:
        stage: build
    
        script:
        - echo building project...
        - C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild /target:Build /property:config=Release /verbosity:q Project1.dproj /p:DCC_BuildAllUnits=true /p:"Platform=Win32"
        - iscc "path/file.iss"
        artifacts:
           name: "test"
           paths:
              - Win32\Release\Project1.exe
```

But, when i execute the pipeline I got this error:

```sh
ISCC : Termine 'ISCC' non riconosciuto come nome di cmdlet, funzione, programma eseguibile o file script. Controllare 
l'ortografia del nome o verificare che il percorso sia incluso e corretto, quindi riprovare.
```

I launch this pipeline in my windows machine and I already add environment variables in the system.

Anyone has idea why is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify the full path to your InnoSetup installation folder, or add the folder to the PATH in System Environment variables.